# Binary Search not working correctly

Tags: c#, listbox

Hi guys I have a binary search, there is a listbox of sorted numbers, and the user enters a value in a textbox to check its position within the listbox. However the number entered in the textbox shows as the positon within the listbox to e.g. 5 entered, "The number you are searcing is found in position 5".

```
            int Number = (Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text));

            int a = lstHoldValue.Items.Count;
            int start = 0, end = a - 1, mid = (start + end) / 2;

            while (start <= end)
            {
                mid = (start + end) / 2;
                if (Number == Convert.ToInt16(lstHoldValue.Items[mid]))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The number you are searching is found in position " + (Number));
                    return;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], bearing in mind that you don't need to use a GUI to demonstrate or test the binary search part itself. You should also look *very carefully* at your `MessageBox.Show` call. What are you using to provide the position, and are you sure that's what you want to be providing? (Hint: when you've got `"..." + (Number)` in your code, you shouldn't be surprised when it shows you the number...)

Comment: Review and debug your code. What is the content of numArray?

Comment: Sorry guys, ive showed you the wrong code, my prior code was working when I used numArray. Although I'm trying to do this with just using the listbox now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary search block is correct

The error is in the message you print. It should be:

```
MessageBox.Show("The number you are searching is found in position " + (mid));
```

**mid** instead of *Number*